# Cómo dar formato con expresión regular a un número en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Estoy realizando un proyecto en `JavaScript` y quisiera realizar una expresión regular para que me de formato a lo siguiente: Tengo los dos siguientes strings: `'$7.000.000'` y `'$7.000.000.00'` en ambos casos quisiera que se quitaran el signo $ y los puntos, pero en el segundo string, además de lo anterior, quisiera que se quitaran los dos últimos ceros, quedando ambos de la siguiente forma: `'7000000'`.

Logré quitar los puntos y el signo $ pero no consigo quitar los dos últimos ceros de ser necesario. Mi código actual luce así:

```
var num = '$7.000.000.00' //o $7.000.000
var numFormat = num.replace(/[$.,\s]/g, '')
```

Cómo podría acomodar mi expresión regular para que, en caso de que existan esos dos ceros al final, los quite?

Comment: Una expresión regular para eso es como usar un cañón para matar un mosquito. Si el formato de tu cadena es siempre el mismo, puedes usar sólo una combinación de `substring` y `parseInt`,`split` y `join`. Igual si lo que te falta es sólo quitar los últimos dos ceros, con hacer un `numFormat = numFormat.substring(0, numFormat.length - 2);` ya le quitas los dos últimos caracteres a tu cadena. Saludos

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, pero el formato de la cadena no siempre termina en .00 en algunas ocasiones viene y en otras no, por eso pensé en la expresión regular

Answer (score 2, accepted):

de más está decir que no puedes usar el punto para separador decimal y de miles al mismo tiempo. Pero imaginando que recibiste los números y ahora hay que limpiarlos: Entonces tu string tiene la forma de

- Un signo monetario (no sé si sale siempre)
- Un número entero
- Cero o más ocurrencias del grupo `.000`
- Cero o más ocurrencias del grupo `.00` o `.0` (si fueran tres entra en el grupo anterior)

Puedes expresar eso como:

```
      ┌─ Uno a tres enteros  (#, ## o ###)
      │   
      │         ┌─ cero o más grupos de '.###'
      │         │           
      │         │           ┌─ cero o más ocurrencias de '.#, .##, ## o #         
  ┌───┴───┐ ┌───┴───┐  ┌────┴────┐       
 /(\d{1,3})((\.\d{3})*)(\.?\d{1,2})*(\d*)$/g
           └─────┬────┘             └─┬─┘└─ fin de la cadena 
                 │                    │
                 │                    └─ 0 a N números hasta el final                        
                 │
                 └─  todos los grupos de '.###' juntos
```

1. El primer grupo es evidente. Accedo a él como `$1` en el reemplazo
2. El segundo captura todas las ocurrencias de un grupo anidado, (el 3)
3. Es el grupo anidado con el patrón '.###'.

   Si yo pusiera como grupo de captura `(\.\{3})*` el `$2` en el reemplazo sería a lo más un grupo `.###` perdiendo los primeros si es que existen.

   `/(\d{1,3})(\.\d{3})*/.exec('$700.000.000')` recibe `$1=700` y `$2=.000`

   `/(\d{1,3})((\.\d{3})*)/.exec('$700.000.000')` recibe `$1=700` `$2=.000.000` y `$3=.000`

   Al anidar el grupo de captura recibo en cambio el conjunto de todos los grupos, e.g. '.000.000.000' como `$2`  y el último "hijo" como `$3`.
4. una combinación de punto y números, o bien sólo números que no formen el patrón `.###`. Me explico

   - 700.000.00 (sobran dos)
   - 700.000.0000 (sobra uno, no necesito un punto para saber que está mal formateado)
5. Si hay más números los recibo acá

   - eg. 700.000.0000.00 (sobran cuatro. el grupo $4 captura el cero sobrante, como ya salimos del grupo 2/3, ya no reacciona al patrón '.###'

```js
const menos_de_100 = '$70',
  trescifras = '$700',
  cuatrocifras = `${menos_de_100}00.000`,
  seiscifras = '$700.000',
  un_decimal = `${trescifras}.0`,
  dos_decimales = `${un_decimal}0`,
  cuatro_decimales = `${dos_decimales}00`,
  dos_y_4_decimales = `${trescifras}.00.0000`,
  cuatro_y_2_decimales = `${trescifras}.0000.00`,
  cuatro_y_3_decimales = `${trescifras}.0000.000`,
  reg_expression = /(\d{1,3})((\.\d{3})*)(\.?\d{0,2})*(\d*)$/g;
  
Object.entries({
    menos_de_100,
    cuatrocifras,
    seiscifras,
    un_decimal,
    dos_decimales,
    cuatro_decimales,
    dos_y_4_decimales,
    cuatro_y_2_decimales,
    cuatro_y_3_decimales
  })
  .forEach(([nombre, cadena]) => {
    let corregida = cadena.replace(reg_expression, '$1$2');
    console.log(`${nombre.padStart(18,' ')}: ${cadena.padStart(12,' ')}`,`-> "${corregida}"`);

  });
```

(y ahora sólo queda reemplazar lo que no sea número por '')

Hay maneras menos elaboradas de hacerlo si quieres apuntar al 80/20. Por ejemplo explotar el número usando el punto, y filtrar el array resultante para tomar los primeros N grupos antes del grupo que no tenga 3 números:

```
nma='$700.000.000.00000.000.00'.split('.'),
 primero=nma.shift();
 nma=nma.slice(0,
   nma.indexOf(
     nma.find(grupo=>{return grupo.length!==3})
    )
   );
 nma=[primero].concat(nma).join('.');
```

Pero eso descarta los grupos de 4 y obviamente no reviso si los grupos son números o emoticons.

Answer (score 2):

Como te digo en mi comentario, me parece que puedes hacer el trabajo sin necesidad de una expresión regular.

Además @ffflabs hace una acotación muy válida y es que por norma general el símbolo de separación decimal debería ser siempre diferente del de separación de miles.

En tu pregunta dices que tienes 2 tipos de cadenas:

```
let cadena1 = '$7.000.000.000.00';
let cadena2 = '$7.000.000.000';
```

En la primera tienes 2 ceros después del último carácter no numérico y en la segunda tienes 3 ceros.

Para *eliminar* los dos ceros y el símbolo monetario, haremos uso de condicionales muy sencillos y de los métodos:

- [`substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/substring), [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/split) y [`concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/concat) del Objeto [String](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String).
- [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/join), [`pop()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/pop) del Objeto [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array).
- [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Number/parseInt) del Objeto [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Number)

Lo primero es deshacernos del símbolo monetario, luego deshacernos de los puntos y por último deshacernos de los ceros finales si ambos son menos de 3 dígitos.

Con esto en mente crearemos una función:

```js
const formatNumber = function(str) {
    // tomamos el valor sin el símbolo monetario
    let result = str.substring(1);

    // variable para almacenar la parte decimal si esta es distinta de cero
    let decimal = '';

    // escribimos un array con los dígitos
    result = result.split('.');

    // si tenemos más de 1 elemento en el array y además
    // el último elemento tiene menos de 3 dígitos y
    if(
      result.length > 1 &&
      result[result.length - 1].length < 3
    ) {
        // si los dígitos del último elemento son todos cero
        // entonces eliminamos el último elemento
        if(!Number.parseInt(result[result.length - 1])) {
            result.pop();
        } else {
            // si los dígitos del último elemento son diferentes de cero
            // almacenamos la parte decimal y
            // entonces eliminamos el último elemento
            decimal = '.'.concat(result[result.length - 1]);
            result.pop();
        }
    }
    return result.join('').concat(decimal);;
}
```

Con esta función hemos eliminado el símbolo monetario, los puntos y los dígitos finales si estos son menos de 3 dígitos y son iguales a cero.

Podemos ver esta función en acción en el siguiente `snippet`:

```js
const formatNumber = function(str) {
    
    let result = str.substring(1);

    result = result.split('.');
    
    let decimal = '';

    if(
      result.length > 1 &&
      result[result.length - 1].length < 3
    ) {
        if(!Number.parseInt(result[result.length - 1])) {
            result.pop();
        } else {
            decimal = '.'.concat(result[result.length - 1]);
            result.pop();
        }
    }
    return result.join('').concat(decimal);
}

const numbers = [
    '$7.000.000.00',
    '$700.000.000',
    '$70',
    '$700.00',
    '$7.000',
    '$7.12',
    '$700.000.31',
];

numbers.forEach(num => {
  console.log(`${num} => ${formatNumber(num)}`);
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Con esto tienes ya una forma de resolver el problema sin pensar en expresiones regulares.